# Login and register is not working in angular8

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8, angular2-forms

I am trying login and register section using reactiveform method in angular 8 but not working.I am not getting any error but when I click submit or register button getting alert message like this :[object Object]. So I can not find the solution.Login and register process not working.If anyone kown please help me to resolve this issue.

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-rfqlxg?file=app%2Fweb%2F_services%2Fuser.service.ts

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getAll() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`/users`);
}

getById(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(`/users/` + id);
}

register(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(`/users/register`, user);
}

update(user: User) {
    return this.http.put(`/users/` + user.id, user);
}

delete(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(`/users/` + id);
}
}
```

authentication.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public currentUser: Observable<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new      BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}

public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}

login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            }

            return user;
        }));
}

logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
}
}
```

Comment: Try `this.alertService.error(error.message);` in your `login.component.ts` at line 57

Comment: Getting this error: Http failure response for https://angular-7-registration-login-example-fthtbb.stackblitz.io/users/authenticate: 403 OK

Comment: @ferhen : How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing [object Object] is because you are passing the entire HttpErrorResponse which is an object . Your alert component template will display it properly if it is not an object.

you can change login form submit method as follows

```
onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error.message);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
```

please change register components submit method as follows

```
 onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error.message);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
```

what i did is passed the message field from error response. if you want to have a logic for different http error codes , you can have it here  and pass a message string to error method based on the error code. please try if you want to handle by error code

```
onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    if(error.staus === 403){
                      this.alertService.error("You are not authorized");
                    }else{
                      this.alertService.error("Something went wrong");
                    }
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

if you want to display the error as it is
change the alert compoenent template as follows

```
<div *ngIf="message" [ngClass]="{ 'alert': message, 'alert-success': message.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': message.type === 'error' }">{{message.text |json}}</div>
```

Comment: Getting Error: Http failure response for https://angular-7-registration-login-example-smrdys.stackblitz.io/users/authenticate: 403 OK

Comment: Your concept is nor working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-smrdys?file=app/web/register/register.component.ts

Comment: That is what you are receiving as error .thats why it is showing that.

Comment: i tested it in your stackblitz link, it is working.

Comment: as of now the we passed what ever the message the field of error response has. in your case it is "Getting Error: Http failure response for angular-7-registration-login-example-smrdys.stackblitz.io/users/…: 403 OK" . if you dont want this message . you can check for status and returna  message

Comment: i updated the answer with handling with error codes

Comment: Please undertand my question. Login and register process not working.Just you register using your email and password then try to login. if it is success it will go to home page Please test it:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-smrdys?file=app%2Fweb%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts

Comment: This is original code.As per this my code is not working.Please check this one also :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example

Comment: you have any solution?

Comment: your application don't used the error interceptor that other application have. in the last shared stackblitz app it is using an interceptor ErrorInterceptor. add that interceptor to your application it will work